# C++ does reference return a lvalue or rvalue?

Tags: c++, reference, lvalue

```
int a, b;
a=10;
&b=a;
```

This simple code causes the following error when compiled.

```
error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

But `&b` is indeed on the left hand-side. So what does the error message exactly mean?

Comment: There is no reference in your code.

Comment: You can't assign a value to a reference. The proper way is `b = a`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Why not just `b = a;`? Are you trying to learn about pointers? Then it would be `int* b = &a;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this context `&` is the *address-of* operator. The value of `&b` is a pointer of type `int *`.  It is a prvalue.   This is unrelated to use of the `&` symbol in a declaration (where it means the declaration of a reference) -- symbols mean different things in declarators than they do in expressions.

You cannot change the address of a variable. Variables have the same address for their whole lifetime.